# Abrir un archivo con contraseña usando Openpyxl teniendo la contraseña

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl

Hola el problema que tengo es que quiero leer una plantilla Excel con contraseña usando openpyxl.
Tengo la contraseña, pero no se como ocuparla ya que load_workbook() no posee la contraseña como parámetro.
Se puede?? o tengo que buscar otra librería
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Por favor, añade lo que hayas intentado, te sugiero que leas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para adaptarte mejor a esta plataforma

Comment: gracias por el comentario, tomaré sus consejos